# Django - Use Python3 or 2.7? Longevity and performance of project

Tags: python, django, version

Although this could be downvoted as an opinion based issue, I suspect there is a concrete answer to this:

- I want to create a future-proof django project.
- I want to maintain the best coding standards
- I do in fact require a diversity of other python modules for the apps I am creating
- I am shooting for best performance

With that in mind, should I stick to python2.7 because of it's great support and use? Or would it be better to use python3 because it is the way of the future?

Comment: The rule of thumb is that you should go with 2 if and only if you plan to use modules that are only available for 2 and cannot be easily built for or ported to 3. That said, yes, this is an opinion.

Answer (score 3):

[Django's official stance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/faq/install/#what-python-version-should-i-use-with-django) is, as long as your dependencies support Python 3, to use Python 3. Python 3 has and will continue to receive new features and improvements, including better performance.

Unless you need modules that would be hard to port to Python 3 (simple ones can often be fixed just by running the builtin 2to3 tool), there isn't any reason not to use Python 3.

Comment: In the last sentence, don't you mean 'can't think of any reason *not* to use Python 3'?

Comment: Good catch, I did mean that. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If the Python modules required are available for Python 3.x, then I would go ahead with the latest stable release. If not, don't be afraid to use Python 2.7 since performance is great and many 3.x improvements have been backported.

However, take into account that sooner or later you'll have to migrate to Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

I would stick to python 2.7. It is more commonly used, and has lots of support.